# Good resources for understanding HTTP, Browsing, caching, web server security etc?

Tags: web-server, http, cache

When I ask questions, many of the times, people leave answers like "first learn about *this (or that)*." The problem is, I don't know if I can find books specifically written on those subjects.

Here are a few I have been advised to learn about (from many questions I've read and asked): Basics and working of...

- HTTP, HTTPS, TCP, UDP
- Browsers
- client - server separation
- Web server security (+ software-based Anti-DDOS techniques)
- virtual hosts (as seen in web servers like Apache)
- caching and cache-control headers (eTags etc)

Please advise good reading resources on the aforementioned subjects (each subject individually).

*[**NOTE:** This question felt more like a Serverfault/stackoverflow mixup. But I am not sure. If anything is wrong, kindly suggest in the comments.]*

Comment: Wikipedia, Google, Amazon Book Store and the Internet in general.

Comment: Requests of lists of resources are not really what SF is meant for.  As mailq says, for any of those topics, you need to Google around and find stuff to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, thought I'd get some advise (it's easy to find a book on a given subject, but a good one is difficult, and since I'd be buying, thought I should ask first).

Anyway, I can't leave this question like this, so I am answering it myself, with the books I found on given topics.

- **HTTP & PROTOCOLS:**

  - [HTTP: The Definitive Guide](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1565925092)
  - [Web Protocols and Practice: HTTP/1.1, Networking Protocols, Caching, and Traffic Measurement](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201710889)
  - [Web Application Architecture: Principles, Protocols and Practices](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/047051860X)
  - [HTTP Developer's Handbook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672324547)
  - [HTTP Essentials: Protocols for Secure, Scaleable Web Sites](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471398233)
- **Web server security:** Most books about Web servers, Apache, Nginx, server administration will cover this.
- **Caching:**

  - [Web Caching (O'Reilly Internet Series)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/156592536X)
  - [Web Content Caching and Distribution](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9048166268)
  - [Web Protocols and Practice: HTTP/1.1, Networking Protocols, Caching, and Traffic Measurement](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201710889)
  - [Web Caching and Replication](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201615703)

*[I'll probably have to update this answer, when actually read some books and find some good ones.]*